# Display particular infos from XML API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following API

```
          <event>
            <match_id>2079876</match_id>
            <o1>2.57</o1>
            <oX>2.70</oX>
            <o2>2.80</o2>
            <oU>1.38</oU>
            <oO>2.52</oO>
            <oG>2.05</oG>
            <oNG>1.58</oNG>
            <p1>2.70</p1>
            <pX>2.81</pX>
            <p2>2.99</p2>
            <pU>1.42</pU>
            <pO>2.82</pO>        
          </event>
          <event>
            <match_id>2081006</match_id>
            <o1>1.12</o1>
            <oX>6.35</oX>
            <o2>14.50</o2>
            <oU>2.95</oU>
            <oO>1.28</oO>
            <oG>1.87</oG>
          </event>
```

and I have a function that fetchs the API and then I created one that gets as input         `<match_id>2079876</match_id>`
and I want to find this id from the xml and display the `<o1>` or `<o2>` depends on the choice

```
function findSpecific(xml, choice, place){
    let matches = xml.getElementsByTagName('event');
    //console.log(matches[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers support (CSS) Query selectors and Xpath expressions on Document instances. Xpath expressions are the more powerful possibility. They support the different node types, complex conditions and XML namespaces.

The expression in the following example matches all elements inside the `event` with a specific `match_id` child.

```js
const events = getXMLDocument();
const dataNodes = events.evaluate(
    '//event[match_id="2081006"]/*', 
    events, 
    null, 
    XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, 
    null
);

const eventData = {};
let dataNode = dataNodes.iterateNext();
while (dataNode) {
  eventData[dataNode.localName] = dataNode.textContent;
  dataNode = dataNodes.iterateNext();
}
console.log(eventData);

function getXMLDocument() {
  const xmlString = `<events>
      <event>
        <match_id>2079876</match_id>
        <o1>2.57</o1>
        <oX>2.70</oX>
        <o2>2.80</o2>
        <oU>1.38</oU>
        <oO>2.52</oO>
        <oG>2.05</oG>
        <oNG>1.58</oNG>
        <p1>2.70</p1>
        <pX>2.81</pX>
        <p2>2.99</p2>
        <pU>1.42</pU>
        <pO>2.82</pO>        
      </event>
      <event>
        <match_id>2081006</match_id>
        <o1>1.12</o1>
        <oX>6.35</oX>
        <o2>14.50</o2>
        <oU>2.95</oU>
        <oO>1.28</oO>
        <oG>1.87</oG>
      </event>
    </events>`;
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlString, 'application/xml');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you think convert to Json and get data what you want.

```js
const xmlSample = '<tag>tag content</tag><tag2>another content</tag2><tag3><insideTag>inside content</insideTag><emptyTag /></tag3>';
console.log(parseXmlToJson(xmlSample));

function parseXmlToJson(xml) {
    const json = {};
    for (const res of xml.matchAll(/(?:<(\w*)(?:\s[^>]*)*>)((?:(?!<\1).)*)(?:<\/\1>)|<(\w*)(?:\s*)*\/>/gm)) {
        const key = res[1] || res[3];
        const value = res[2] && parseXmlToJson(res[2]);
        json[key] = ((value && Object.keys(value).length) ? value : res[2]) || null;

    }
    return json;
}
```

Comment: How can i convert it if it is a link? Plus the XML is in very bad format that i cannot change it